# Sql query to get friends of a contact's children who are friends of user's children

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables namely

```
UserContact /*Saves the user and his contacts information*/
user_id | contact_id

AdultChild /*Saves information about a user and his children*/
user_id. | child_id

UserFriends /*Saves information about a child and his friends*/
child_id | friend_id
```

The `user_id`, `child_id` and `friend_id` reference the `UserTable`. The children of contact and user are stored in `AdultChild` table. Similarly the friends of contacts children and users children are stored in `UserFriend` table.

For `UserContact` table is there a way to query all the friends of contacts children who are friends of user children.

I tried the following query

```
select
    c.user_id, c.contact_id, c.relationship, a.adult_id, a.child_id, f.friend_id
from mkw_user_contact c
    inner join mkw_adult_child a on a.adult_id = c.contact_id
    inner join mkw_user_friend f on a.child_id = f.user_id
where c.user_id =19061 ;
```

Comment: please tag which DBMS you are using as solutions can vary, also please add some sample data and expected output

Comment: Can you provide the sql query you tried (the one that isn't working), as well as some sample data? From your description, it isn't obvious whether the children of a contact are stored in the AdultChild table.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
select cf.friend_id
  from user_contact c
  join adult_child cc on cc.user_id = c.contact_id
  join user_friends cf on cf.child_id = cc.child_id
  join adult_child uc on uc.user_id = c.user_id
  join user_friends uf on uf.child_id = uc.child_id
  where c.user_id = 19061
    and cf.friend_id = uf.friend_id;
```

Assuming your tables are like this:

```
create table user_table (
  user_id int primary key not null, 
  name varchar(20)
);

create table user_contact (
  user_id int, 
  contact_id int,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (user_id) references user_table (user_id),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (contact_id) references user_table (user_id)
);

create table adult_child (
  user_id int, 
  child_id int,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (user_id) references user_table (user_id),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (child_id) references user_table (user_id)
);

create table user_friends (
  child_id int, 
  friend_id int,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (child_id) references user_table (user_id),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (friend_id) references user_table (user_id)
);
```